# Android talkback highlighted area floats on page scroll

Tags: android, html, ionic-framework, accessibility

When selecting an item with TalkBack on, the highlighted box appears over the element (as expected). 
However when I scroll the page itself (2 finger scroll) the highlighted box floats at its current location, it doesn't stay pegged to the element (graphically).

An unintended consequence of this is that I can line up the highlight box with another element and double tap (a button for example), the button underneath will be selected.
However when I swipe next to the next element, the 'next element' is the element after the originally focused element.

For the life of me I can't figure out what could be causing this odd behaviour. If I go to a different site (like google search for example), the highlighted box stays with the selected element when scrolling, so the further issues do not come up. It tells me that I'm doing something in my app which is funky, but I don't know what could be the culprit.

Image example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXHmV.jpg

This is in an ionic framework based angular application.

Any ideas of what areas I can look into more?